# formLabels are shown at top left in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have tried many things to show the labels to the left but they keep showing up at top left. What might be the cause?

[image]

The actual code is 3105 lines. The related code is:

```
var bildirilenArizaAlt = new Ext.form.FormPanel({

    frame : true,
    id: "bildirilenArizaAltid",
    layout: {
        type: 'table',
        columns: 2
    },
    defaults : {
        padding : 0,
        width : 245,
        cellCls : 'verticalAlignTop',
        border : false,    
    },
    labelWidth: 30,
    labelAlign:  'right',
    items: [{
        layout:'form',
        items:[{
            xtype : 'dynaCombo',
            table : 'TANIMLAR_DET',
            field : 'TANIM_DET_ADI',
            no : 'TANIM_DET_NO',
            id: 'bildirilenArizaAltbir',
            fieldLabel : LANG.ISEMRI__SERVIS_TURU,
            hiddenName : "SERVIS_TURU",
            forceSelection : true,
            readOnly: (loggedUser.domain == "demo") ? true : false,
            where : [{
                field : 'TANIM_NO',
                value : 1,
                queryType : 0,
                whereType : 'and',
                searchType : 'default'
            }]
        }]
    },{
        layout:'form',
        items:[{
            xtype : 'textfield',
            name : 'SERVIS_VEREN',
            id : 'SERVIS_VERENba',
            allowBlank: false,
            readOnly: true,
            fieldLabel : 'Ekip'}]
    },{
        layout:'form',
        items:[{
        layout: 'form',
        items:[{
            xtype : 'textfield',
            id: 'montaj_kart_no_id',
            fieldLabel: LANG.ISEMRI__MOUNT_CARD_NO,
            name : 'MONTAJ_KART_NO'
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This label behavior means that label too long or panel width too small. Try change panel size and labelWidth.